# marker not show up in hicghstock with more than 1000 point

Tags: highcharts, marker

I have a highstock chart with more than 1000 points and 3 series, one of them is just a line series with a few data for some dates and i want them to be visible in every zoom, but right now with zoom in and to that point it show up, how can i make highstock check for every single point and show it's marker without considering any thing beside?

i already tried below but it have no effect:

```
 plotOptions: {
      series: {
        turboThreshold: 0,
      },
    },
```

in here  i put an example and you see marker not appear in first load, but afrer zooming to end, it show up:

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kingofday/8bsrcoxn/16/)

Comment: Try using [series.scatter](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.scatter) to mark markers on chart, it should be a better approach to mark something on chart.

Comment: thank you, using 'sctatter' for type, solved the issue